# React Native Expo Location Permissions, requestForegroundPermissionsAsync, requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync how make them work

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on an app that records the location when the aplication is active or in the background.

After Permissions.getAsync got depricated, my app is not recording the coordonates when in background.

I understand I have to change to requestForegroundPermissionsAsync and requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync but I can not make it work.(I don't know how to use requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync)

Here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Accuracy,
  requestForegroundPermissionsAsync,
  requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync,
  watchPositionAsync
} from 'expo-location';

export default (shouldTrack, callback) => {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscriber;
    const startWatching = async () => {
      try {
        
        const { granted } = await requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
           if (!granted) {
             throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
         }
        
        subscriber = await watchPositionAsync(
          {
            accuracy: Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
            timeInterval: 1000,
            distanceInterval: 10
          },
          callback
        );
      } catch (e) {
        setErr(e);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Question needs additional information to troubleshoot. For starters, are you on iOS\Android\both? Does it work on one platform but not the other? What permissions are listed in app.json (is this a managed\bare workflow)? Are the foreground updates working? Background updates require additional code and none of that is included here.

Have you gone through Expo's documentation? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location